# Get DataGridViewComboboxColumn SelectedValue (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, reference, null, selectedvalue, datagridviewcombobox

I need to get the selected value of a ComboBox in a DataGridView. I have it partially working, but I get a *Null Reference Exception* if I change a another ComboBox in the grid. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub dgvSampleList_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgvSampleList.EditingControlShowing
    Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)

    If (comboBox IsNot Nothing) Then
        'Remove an existing event-handler
        RemoveHandler comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)

        'Add the event handler. 
        AddHandler comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    'Display selected value
    MsgBox("ProgramID: " & comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString)
End Sub
```

This works fine the first time the ComboBox is changed, but generates a Null Reference Exception if another ComboBox is changed. Any ideas why this is happening? Note: I found most this code on MSDN's discussion forms.

Thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 2):

It's best to avoid global variables when they are unnecessary.

You just need to test for whether comboBox is nothing before trying to access a property of `comboBox`:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim comboBox As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    'Display selected value
    If comboBox IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox("ProgramID: " & comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

It seems to me that when the `comboBox` is set from an old value to the new value, that this SelectedIndexChanged event gets called for both the old and new comboboxes. I suspect that when it gets called for the old `comboBox`, the sender is null/Nothing because its value is getting changed. Maybe. But no matter what it is happening, a null is a null. Just test that it's not null before you try to access any of its properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for `comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString` instead of `comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Sorted out by making small changes in the codes.

Declare a global variable

```
Dim comboBoxCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
Dim gol As Integer = 0



 Dim comboBox As ComboBox
    Private Sub dgvSampleList_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DGVItems.EditingControlShowing
        comboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)

        If (comboBox IsNot Nothing) Then

            'Add the event handler.  
            AddHandler comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
            gol = 1
            'AddHandler comboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        comboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
        If gol = 1 Then
            Dim item As String = comboBox.Text
            MsgBox(item)
            gol = 0
        End If
  End Sub
```