# VB.Net Datagridview combobox add a handler

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I've spent a day trying to figure out how to solve my problem, which is identical to

[this related unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326676/get-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-selectedvalue-vb-net)

On the first combobox, my code works fine, no problem. When I try to change the combobox it throws an error `Null Reference Exception`

This is my code:

```
Private Sub dgvSurveyQuestions_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgvSurveyQuestions.EditingControlShowing
    
    Dim editingComboBox As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
    If Not editingComboBox Is Nothing Then
        'Add the handle to your IndexChanged Event

        RemoveHandler editingComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf editingComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged
        AddHandler editingComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf editingComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged

    End If

    'Prevent this event from firing twice, as is normally the case.
    'RemoveHandler dgvSurveyQuestions.EditingControlShowing, AddressOf dgvSurveyQuestions_EditingControlShowing

End Sub

Private Sub editingComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim editingComboBox As ComboBox = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)
    If editingComboBox Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Show your Message Boxes
    MessageBox.Show(editingComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString)  ' throws error here

End Sub
```

I'm still working on a different workaround, like adding a handler while the datagridview is populated or whatever.. I don't even know if this is possible but I need to do this. 
I'm really stuck here, can someone shed some light and advice me on what to do? Thanks

Comment: Could you debug and tell us what is exactly the `TryCast` returning to the variable `editingComboBox`?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ have you any speculation? TryCast returns a reference (which is irrelevant what type, as long as the error is `Null Reference Exception`) or Nothing (Then the line in which the error occurred, should not be performed - `If editingComboBox Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`).

Comment: @lomed no speculation, the ´Nothing´ case of the ´Trycast´ is managed already so i feel like the problem is that ´combobox.selectedValue ´ is nothing, that's why i was asking to debug. I don't see any other reason to throw a null exception there

Comment: @MatteoNNZ you right.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check if `editingComboBox.SelectedValue` is *Nothing*.

The `DataGridView` reuses only one `ComboBox` instance, and internally resets the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox` when the user selects another `ComboBox` cell.
Then the event `SelectedIndexChanged` raises and `SelectedValue` will be *Nothing* at that time.

Comment: @lomed, please read well the answer, Ripple is writing "selectedValue" which is a property that can return Nothing in case of Non-DataBinding. Moreover, it's really the only reason why he's getting Null Exception in that part of code. For sake of honesty remove the downvote.

Comment: Great @lomed. I really believe this must be the problem, let's wait for asker feedback